# Monolog Error After 2.2 Upgrade

Tags: magento2, psr-logger

After an upgrade from 2.1.9 to 2.2.2, I am getting an error with the use of a Logger class in a custom module.  The error is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to
>   Biztech\Auspost\Model\Carrier\Auspost::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Logger, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog given, called in
>   /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/magento-2.2/app/code/Biztech/Auspost/Model/Carrier/Auspost.php:55\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/magento-2.2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Biztech\Auspost\Model\Carrier\Auspost->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog),
>   Object(Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager),
>   Object(Biztech\Auspost\Helper\Data),
>   Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\I in
>   /var/www/html/magento-2.2/app/code/Biztech/Auspost/Model/Carrier/Auspost.php
>   on line 55

I am definitely passing an instance of Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Logger, so I am not sure why Magento thinks it is an instance of Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog

The Logger class is defined as:

```
<?php

namespace Biztech\Auspost\Logger;

class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger {

}
```

And is called with this constructor:

```
<?php
namespace Biztech\Auspost\Model\Carrier;

...
use Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Logger;

protected $_logger;

class Auspost extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{

  ...

public function __construct(
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Logger $logger
    ....
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
```

I also have a di.xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">auspost</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Biztech\Auspost\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: can you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command then check ?